# Pythonic Method for handling None and with Statement

Tags: python, with-statement

I want to call a function and either pass a `File`-like object or `None`. But, using the `File`-like object, I want to handle its resource allocation properly with the `with` statement. But, Python will raise an exception (`AttributeError`) if my `with` expression evaluates to `None`. I suppose I could write the full `try`/`except` block longhand, but does a concise Pythonic way of handling this situation exist?

```
def call_method(o1, o2, f_in):
    if f_in:
        pass # Do something optional if we have the f_in value

# ...

with (open(path, 'rb') if flag else None) as f_in:
    call_method(opt1, opt2, f_in)
    # Throws an AttributeError, since None does not have __exit__
```

Comment: What function takes a file object or `None`? That seems like the real problem here. Can you rewrite it?

Comment: It wouldn't be possible to just use a simple if statement to check the flag, and then decide whether you use the file-like object or call the function with `None`?

Comment: @wjandrea: I suppose I could make the function into a class and have a main processing method, but an optional method a caller could invoke beforehand with the `File` object. Are you suggesting that is the Pythonic way to handle this?

Comment: @palswim I don't know about Pythonic cause I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but fwiw your idea sounds good.

Comment: @wjandrea: For a little more context, I am trying to write a command-line application using `argparse`, but I don't want to reference the arguments directly in the function (so that I could use the function if I wanted to load the code as a module as well). So, I am trying to assign an optional input file to a variable, like `with ((sys.stdin if args.opt_file == '-' else open(args.opt_file, 'rb')) if args.opt_file else None) as f_in:`

Comment: @palswim Oh yeah, that should definitely be handled outside the function. And you should explicitly check `if args.opt_file is not None` instead of `if args.opt_file` since a null string is also falsy, but should trigger a different error (file does not exist).

Comment: BTW `argparse` has a `FileType` type but it leaves the file handle open.

Comment: @AMC: That sounds like an answer to me. In fact, just like [an answer somebody has posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61492551/393280) already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a context manager that does nothing, that's [`contextlib.nullcontext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nullcontext), not `None`:

```
import contextlib

with (open(whatever) if flag else contextlib.nullcontext()) as f:
    do_whatever()
```

`f` will be `None` in the `not flag` case - the thing that gets assigned to `f` is `__enter__`'s return value, which doesn't have to be the context manager itself.

Comment: Nice one for anyone using Python 3.7 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

The fact of the matter is that you cannot pass `None` to `with` since `__exit__` is called when `with` is finished.  Instead, rearrange to this:

```
def call_method(o1, o2, f_in):
    # If nothing special is done with None (just a pass) then you don't
    # even need to call this with None, otherwise, you can check f_in like:
    if f_in is None:
        pass
    else:
        pass

if flag:
    with open(path, 'rb') as f_in:
        call_method(opt1, opt2, f_in)
else:
    # only really needed if call_method does something if None is passed
    call_method(opt1, opt2, None)
```

Another option is to use a `nullcontext()` in place of `None` as stated in another answer

Comment: If `call_method` does something special with `None`, then yes, you can have the `else` branch for that.  I'll add it in

Answer (score 0):

For Python < 3.7, I have accomplished this with a `lambda` expression:

```
def call_method(o1, o2, get_file):
    if get_file:
        with (get_file() as f_in):
            pass # Do something optional if we have the f_in value

# ...

get_file = (lambda: open(path, 'rb')) if flag else None
call_method(opt1, opt2, get_file)
```

Comment: And in this contrived example, I could have easily just used the `path` variable as a the `flag` and passed it to the function instead, but if more variables determine which file to open, then this approach will cause maintenance nightmares.

Answer (score -1):

The way to do so would be to use try/except:

```
try:
    with open(path) as f:
        ...
except OSError:
    pass
```

The above code is if you intend to do something with the file/ change it in order to avoid race condition.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the problem. `with` statements are used so that files are closed once they're no longer needed. Whether the file exists or not is another topic. And actually you should always use the try-except in order to avoid the race condition.

Comment: @wjandrea You are correct, I will update my post. Sorry for the misunderstanding